# How to print href that has a certain word in the table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web application and I want to print only the href links that have the text "Show on diagram" associated with it.

here is a screenshot of the html i am trying to get to print:

[web application code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0NLS.png)

here is my python code i am using:

```
import webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def cllicheck(clli): #checks to see if there is exactly 8 characters in the clli input
    #print "in the clli checker"
    if len(clli) == 8:
        return True
    else:
        print('Invalid CLLI') 
        return

def drawing(CLLI):
    if cllicheck(CLLI) == True:
        CLLIstate = CLLI[4:6]
        #print "------- Netviz", NetvizCLLI, "was entered ----------"
        resultStr = 'https://gpn.prod.att.com/netTerrain/Search?q=' + CLLI + '&subDiagrams=False&exactMatch=False&filter=Title' 
        webbrowser.open(resultStr)
        r = requests.get(resultStr)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.find_all('a', 'Show on diagram', href=True):
            print (link['href'])
        main()
    else:
        print ('Please Enter 8 Characters')
        main()

def main (): 
#Beginning function to prompt user for CLLI
    print ('\nPlease Enter CLLI.\n')
    CLLI = input()
    drawing(CLLI)

main() #This begins the GPN Program
```

when i run this, it prints nothing out.

I am using this portion of code in hopes of returning the href link:

```
 for link in soup.find_all('a', 'Show on diagram', href=True):
            print (link['href'])
```

I am expecting the link shown on the web screenshot to be displayed/printed when i run this code

Comment: Did you check the documentation of [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)?

Comment: You need to use `string='Show on diagram'` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wrote an answer, because the answer is already in the comments by @Barmar.

You need to use `string='Show on diagram'` https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', string='Show on diagram', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```